# how to install docker on offline centos(7.5)?

Tags: docker, centos, centos7, offline-mode

I want to install docker on an offline centos server .I have another centos server with internet access,my confession is when I go to download needed rpm packages from : https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/
I don't understand which version of a rpm package is compatible with another rpm package(for example : which version of docker-ce is compatible with what version of docker-ce-cli)

is there anyway to download all needed packages to install docker-ce on online centos server and copy and install it on offline centos server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an online machine run

```
sudo yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp/ <YUM_PACKAGE_NAME
```

Copy all the packages to the offline machine and run

```
sudo yum localinstall <LIST_OF_PATHs_TO_DOWNLOADED_PACKAGES>
```

More info here specific to an offline installation of syslog-ng is here: https://isbyr.com/syslog-ng-offline-installation-for-centos-rhel/

Answer (score 0):

Docker installation on offline centos server :
1.on a centos server with internet access , follow these steps :
•   yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly :
•   sudo yum install -y yum-utils : Install the yum-utils package (which provides the yum-config-manager utility) and set up the repository.
•   sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
•   yum repolist : check added repository
•   sudo yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=/home/docker/ install docker-ce-20.10.8 : in this step you can download your desired docker-ce version.this command download docker-ce and all dependencies.
•   copy all downloaded .rpm files in a diectory in offline server
•   yum localinstall *.rpm : run this command In that directory